# Selecting from another table without a join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a working query below but I need to select first and last names for these agents in my select statement, without any real value to join the table on.

My other table is ambition.ambition_users and it has first_name, last_name and extension. I have the subqueries pulling the extensions correctly and treating it as `id`. However, in my main select, I want to also select first_name and last_name. I can't seem to find a way to do this with a simple subquery and I don't have anything to join the table on UNLESS I'm able to join my created `id` on ambition_users.extention.

What's the best way to achieve pulling first and last name without affecting the aggregations of the current query?

Here's the working query:

```
select
case 
when callingpartyno       in (select extension from ambition.ambition_users)
then callingpartyno
when finallycalledpartyno in (select extension from ambition.ambition_users)
then finallycalledpartyno
 end as id

-- this is where i want to select first_name and last_name from ambition.ambition_users

, sum(duration) as total_talk_time_seconds
, round(sum(duration) / 60,2) as total_talk_time_minutes
, sum(if(legtype1 = 1,1,0)) as total_outbound
, sum(if(legtype1 = 2,1,0) and answered = 1) as total_inbound
, sum(if(legtype1 = 2,1,0) and answered = 0) as total_missed
, sum(if(legtype1 = 1, 1, 0)) +                   -- outbound calls
 sum(if(legtype1 = 2, 1, 0))  as total_calls
, now() as time_of_report
, curdate() as date_of_report
 from 
  ambition.session a
  join ambition.callsummary b
  on a.notablecallid = b.notablecallid
 where 
date(a.ts) >= curdate()
 and (
callingpartyno in (select extension from ambition.ambition_users
)
 or  finallycalledpartyno in (select extension from ambition.ambition_users
)
)
 group by
 id;
```

Comment: You don't want to `select from mytable`?

Comment: Well I'm selecting from the main table and joining another because they contain the call info that aggregates the numbers, and that's all working properly. However, I just want to select the names for the agents based on their extensions

Comment: Knowing your previous questions I would rewrite your CASE expression and use it for a join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you need so many subqueries. You can use a left join and take out all other subqueries.

```
    select
    COALESCE( callingpartyno, finallycalledpartyno) as id
    -- if extension is not equal to callingpartyno, it will return null because its a left join. If you use coalesce you can get the first non null value.

    , max(c.firstname)
    , max(c.lastname)
    -- if you use max you need not put that in group by clause

    , sum(duration) as total_talk_time_seconds
    , round(sum(duration) / 60,2) as total_talk_time_minutes
    , sum(if(legtype1 = 1,1,0)) as total_outbound
    , sum(if(legtype1 = 2,1,0) and answered = 1) as total_inbound
    , sum(if(legtype1 = 2,1,0) and answered = 0) as total_missed
    , sum(if(legtype1 = 1, 1, 0)) +                   -- outbound calls
     sum(if(legtype1 = 2, 1, 0))  as total_calls
    , now() as time_of_report
    , curdate() as date_of_report
     from 
      ambition.session a
      join ambition.callsummary b
      on a.notablecallid = b.notablecallid
---- adding a left join
    left join 
     ambition.users c
    on c.extension = callingpartyno or c.extension = finallycalledpartyno
     where 
    date(a.ts) >= curdate()
     group by id;
```

Comment: Sorry, is this still incomplete slightly?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get relationship among your tables, but you can use below logic to get first and last name with subqueries within the select statement

```
    select
    case 
    when callingpartyno       in (select extension from ambition.ambition_users)
    then callingpartyno
    when finallycalledpartyno in (select extension from ambition.ambition_users)
    then finallycalledpartyno
     end as id

    -- this is where i want to select first_name and last_name from ambition.ambition_users

Max((select firstname from ambition.ambition_users as t1 where t1. Extension=b.callingpartyno)),
Max((select lastname from ambition.ambition_users as t1 where t1. Extension=b.callingpartyno)),

    , sum(duration) as total_talk_time_seconds
    , round(sum(duration) / 60,2) as total_talk_time_minutes
    , sum(if(legtype1 = 1,1,0)) as total_outbound
    , sum(if(legtype1 = 2,1,0) and answered = 1) as total_inbound
    , sum(if(legtype1 = 2,1,0) and answered = 0) as total_missed
    , sum(if(legtype1 = 1, 1, 0)) +                   -- outbound calls
     sum(if(legtype1 = 2, 1, 0))  as total_calls
    , now() as time_of_report
    , curdate() as date_of_report
     from 
      ambition.session a
      join ambition.callsummary b
      on a.notablecallid = b.notablecallid
     where 
    date(a.ts) >= curdate()
     and (
    callingpartyno in (select extension from ambition.ambition_users
    )
     or  finallycalledpartyno in (select extension from ambition.ambition_users
    )
    )
     group by
     id;
```

Comment: This does seem to work except 3 of the first and last names returned null, and the other 7 returned properly. Do you know of a reason that would be? Is there a way to do it without MAX?

Comment: Try putting `or` condition within subquery where clause it will work fine,  max should be there because you are doing group by other columns

Comment: Actually, I got it by using finallycalledpartyno in the subqueries

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using same subquery again & again, i'll advise you to store the result of subquery in a variable.

Also you can write different queries for `callingpartyno` and `finallycalledpartyno` and later merged results with `UNION` as follows:

```
select @ext := Group_concat(distinct extension separator ',') from ambition.ambition_users;

select tmp.*,
(select firstn from ambition.ambition_users where tmp.id = extension) as First_Name,
(select lastn from ambition.ambition_users where tmp.id = extension) as Last_Name
From
(select
 callingpartyno as id
, sum(duration) as total_talk_time_seconds
, round(sum(duration) / 60,2) as total_talk_time_minutes
, sum(if(legtype1 = 1,1,0)) as total_outbound
, sum(if(legtype1 = 2,1,0) and answered = 1) as total_inbound
, sum(if(legtype1 = 2,1,0) and answered = 0) as total_missed
, sum(if(legtype1 = 1, 1, 0)) +                   -- outbound calls
 sum(if(legtype1 = 2, 1, 0))  as total_calls
, now() as time_of_report
, curdate() as date_of_report
 from 
  ambition.session a
  join ambition.callsummary b
  on a.notablecallid = b.notablecallid
 where 
date(a.ts) >= curdate()
 and 
callingpartyno in (@ext)
group by callingpartyno)

      UNION

(select
 finallycalledpartyno  as id
, sum(duration) as total_talk_time_seconds
, round(sum(duration) / 60,2) as total_talk_time_minutes
, sum(if(legtype1 = 1,1,0)) as total_outbound
, sum(if(legtype1 = 2,1,0) and answered = 1) as total_inbound
, sum(if(legtype1 = 2,1,0) and answered = 0) as total_missed
, sum(if(legtype1 = 1, 1, 0)) +                   -- outbound calls
 sum(if(legtype1 = 2, 1, 0))  as total_calls
, now() as time_of_report
, curdate() as date_of_report
 from 
  ambition.session a
  join ambition.callsummary b
  on a.notablecallid = b.notablecallid
 where 
date(a.ts) >= curdate()
 and 
finallycalledpartyno  in (@ext)
group by finallycalledpartyno) 
) tmp;
```